# Difficulty removing corrupt directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, raid, filesystem-corruption

I have two disks in raid 0. I ran fsck on them and long story short, didn't fix it completely.  I found it is all in a single directory. I dont mind losing this dir completely so i tried to rm it.

I have tried rm -rf as root, and deleting it using its inode number. But all I get is "ext3-fs error htree_dirblock_to_tree: bad entry in dir #********: inode number out of bounds".

I haven't found anything able to remove it. Is there some way I can get the FS just to drop the reference?

Comment: Mind sharing with us how did you run `fsck`?

Comment: fsck /dev/md127 -- it came up with stuff like "fsck error could not allocate block" and "error allocating in block group contiguous inode table could not allocate"

Comment: have you unmounted it?

Comment: it was unmounted when i ran fsck, its mounted atm and im trying to remove this directory

Comment: do you know the /dev/sd** of the disks in raid? if so i recommend trying fsck on each disk indepently

Comment: How full is your disk?

Comment: kk, ill try that on each disk seperately. @KenL, it is quite full. du said 93%

Comment: Although in theory it should not be a problem the disk at 93% could be a problem if you have data that you can delete if the separate disk fails try deleting anything that you don't need and rerun

Comment: 93% seems not too full... how about to check with `-f` option (Force checking)?  Alternatively, use an alternative superblock with option `-b`: find out your block size `tune2fs -l /dev/md127 | grep -i 'block size'` and run `e2fsck` with `-b xxx` where xxx is 8193 if block size is 1K, or 16384 for 2K block and 32768 for 4K block size.  See `man e2fsck` for details.

Comment: ok, will do. worst comes to worst i already have everything else copied n ill just wipe and copy back. Its just frustrating that its 6tb and one dir is corrupt which i can't remove :/ i feel like it shouldn't have to come to that

Answer (score 1):

I forgot about this post sorry :/

I found the issue. The bus between CPU/memory on the motherboard failed (just a few bits of it). Hence all the strangeness (as well as kernel panics on live images).

Thanks everyone for your help!